# POST requests are not kept alive

Tags: node.js, http, request

I'm working on a web client that needs to authenticate with a server using NTLM. Since NTLM authenticates the connection I absolutely need to connection to be kept alive to properly do the handshake. I got everything to work with GET requests (for the handshake and the actual request) with the request library but I cannot get it to work with POST requests. Trying to debug the problem using Charles (web proxy) and the only difference I'm seeing between the GET and POST requests is this:

**GET**:
[image]

**POST**:

[image]

As you can see it seems the POST requests are not kept alive. I'm using the `'Connection': 'keep-alive'` headers in both cases. Actually the requests are exactly the same except for the method.

Is this a problem with the request library? 
Does node automatically close connections for POST requests? 
How can I make sure the connection is kept alive?

Comment: Who knows without seeing your code?

Answer (score -1):

Try editing the ht access file or if you can the best bait the php.ini file. Edit the required changes such as max time for a POST and max size for a POST. that way I believe your problem can be solved. if you need the changes required let me know.

FYI: If u want to override your php settings without help from ur server support team, these are the 4 methods to do it

Using PHP

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
ini_set('max_input_time', '1500');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '1500'); 

<input type="hidden" name="max_execution_time" value="2000"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="max_input_time" value="2000"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="upload_max_filesize" value="105M"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="post_max_size" value="105M"/>
```

Now using the .htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize "105M"
php_value post_max_size "105M"
php_value max_input_time "1500"
php_value max_execution_time "1500"  

#<IfModule mod_php5.c>
#php_value post_max_size 200M
#php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
#php_value memory_limit 300M
#php_value max_execution_time 259200
#php_value max_input_time 259200
#php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
#</IfModule>
```

Now using htaccess

```
------NEW php.ini---------
upload_max_filesize = 105M
post_max_size = 105M
max_execution_time = 1500
max_input_time = 1500 
--------------/php.ini---------
```